# C++ using namespaces for versioning can cause inheritance problems with overrides

Tags: c++11, namespaces, overriding, api-design, binary-compatibility

We are trying to namespace the versions of our API with namespaces, although we figured that we will be getting some problems with virtual functions :

```
namespace v1 {
    class someParam {
    public:
        someParam() {};
        virtual ~someParam() {};
    };

    class someClass {
    public:
        someClass() {};
        virtual ~someClass() {};
        virtual bool doSomething(someParam a);
    };


    bool someClass::doSomething(someParam a)
    {
        return true;
    }
}

namespace v2 {

    class someParam : public v1::someParam {
    public:
        bool doParamStuff();
    };
    bool someParam::doParamStuff()
    {
        return true;
    }
}

// Type Aliasing for v2 API
using someClass = v1::someClass;
using someParam = v2::someParam;

// SOME OTHER PROGRAM
class plugin : public someClass
{
public:
    plugin() {};
    virtual ~plugin() {};
    bool doSomething(someParam a) override;

};
```

In this specific case, we are creating extension of existing classes to allow binary compatibility. Although, we get a compilation error for plugin::doSomething because of the override keyword as it is not overriding someClass::doSomething because: 
plugin::doSomething(v2::someParam) vs someClass::doSomething(v1::someParam).

Is there any way to fix up the plugin without explicitely using v1 for someParam in plugin class ? Ideally, nothing should be done on the plugin side, and without having to create v2::someClass

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
virtual bool doSomething(::v1::someParam a)
```

specifies a binary (and C++) interface.  You cannot override it with

```
virtual bool doSomething(::v2::someParam a)
```

as that is a different type.  They are not compatible.  These signatures are unrelated.

When you update `someParam`, you must also update every interface that uses `someParam`, and then every interface that uses those interfaces, etc.

So, in `namespace v2`:

```
class someClass: ::v1::someClass {
public:
    virtual bool doSomething(::v1::someParam a) override final;
    virtual bool doSomething(someParam a);
};
```

and in `doSomething(v1::someParam)` describe how to generate a `v2::someParam` and pass it to the new `doSomething`.

If you cannot do this, you instead have to do this:

```
class someClass {
public:
    virtual bool doSomething(someParam a);
};
```

and make `v2::someClass` a type unrelated to `v1::someClass`.

Regardless, you do

```
using someClass = v2::someClass;
```

Now, instead of using `using` declarations, you can instead conditually use `inline namespace`s.

When you update a version, make the current version the `inline` namespace.  The others are normal namespaces.

Code will now silently start using the `inline namespace` that is "current".

You can import types from previous namespaces by `using symbol = ::library_ns::v1::symbol;`  This should only be done when that type is unchanged, as well as all of its parameters.

---

Now, if your `::v2::someParam` is only a helper, you can split `someParamArg` from `someParamInstance` types.

`someParamArg` would then be the argument type of the root of the `someParam` heirarchy (`::v1::someParam`), while `someParamInstance` would be `::v2::someParam`; what people should create when they want to use it.

In this case, `someParamArg` needs to be able to consider *every* state of `someParamInstance`, even those from later versions.  Hence this only works if `::v2::someParam` is essentially a helper, or if it supports internal value-type polymorphism.